# I want to allocate memory for 700 MB to 800 MB Image size

Tags: cocoa

I am trying to allocate memory 
NSImage*originalLocationImage;

NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:originalLocation];  //originalLocation is file path in my disk

originalLocationImage = [[NSImage alloc]initByReferencingURL:fileURL];

```
NSBitmapImageRep *sourceRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]initWithData:[SourceImage TIFFRepresentation]]  //this line fails to allocate memory
```

and it fails for large Images/

and throws error

```
malloc: *** mmap(size=268435456) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

for small images it works properly.

any help??

Answer (score 2):

Using libjpeg might be an option, it seems to be able to do an optimized sub-scaling up to 16: http://jpegclub.org/djpeg/.

libjpeg is plain C, so you can call it from Objective-C.

Comment: Ihave problem with this line of code that too with tiff images 
I tried Images 1 GB size psd that works fine
NSBitmapImageRep *sourceRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]initWithData:[SourceImage TIFFRepresentation]]  //this line fails to allocate memory

any suggestion for this how to allocate memory in this case.

Comment: additional error I am getting for tiff images is
 <Error>: tiff data provider: No space to fetch tag value.

Comment: if the same cline of code will load one GB psd Image then why not tiff?

Comment: You cannot achieve what you want using NSImage. Do not forget that JPEG is a compressed format so a 800 MB JPEG is a representation for a 2-3 Gb file. NSImage will try to decompress the 800 MB JPEG so you can't use it - you have to use something low level such as libjpeg or implement the access yourself as Blidy suggested.

Comment: Although NSImage appears as a single implementation behind the scenes it treats image formats using different code. PSD != JPG != TIFF. There's one implementation per image format even though you don't see that when calling initWithData.

Comment: This brings up an interesting question though. I'm pretty sure I've loaded 800mb+ NASA images in Preview.app, Safari, etc before, so what is Apple using behind the scenes if not NSImage?

Comment: thanks for all your help. I have the trouble for now how should I  read it line by line.

Comment: I've seen Preview behaving admirably on large JPEGs too but I wouldn't be surprised is there's private frameworks at play there - there's a number of CGImage calls showing up in "nm" that look like private calls such as CGImageCreateByScaling. If I were to tackle this problem I'd investigate CGImageRef and CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex - my hunch is CGImage is better suited for large stuff.

Comment: or is there any other to do this. I have gone through Quicklook framework but there I could not see more useful API to create preview and thumbnail the way I want.

Comment: CGImageRef ref = QLThumbnailImageCreate(kCFAllocatorMallocZone, 
                                            (CFURLRef)fileURL, 
                                            CGSizeMake(size.width, size.height),
                                            (CFDictionaryRef)dict);

there is no way to set resolution thr this API

Answer (score 1):

I'd question why you want to load all of the image into memory in the first place - surely dealing with it like a tile set would be a better option?

You are getting this message because, whilst you might have this much memory free, you don't have this much *contiguous* memory free

Comment: after that I want to create preview of that Image so what would be the better way to do that. I tried so many thing but now could not find any way.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is a preview, you could read it line by line, skipping every n lines and for each line, skip every n pixels. You're left with a (way) smaller image that you can pass through more sophisticated scaling algorithms if necessary, or you can just save it as your thumbnail image or whatever.

Comment: Your proposed solution sounds nice but since the format is likely to be compressed he can't binary skip input - he has to decompress and then skip data out of the decompressed output.

Comment: Yes but you can decompress in chunks, you don't have to read the entire image to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to create a preview of the image, CGImageSource has APIs specifcally for that. They are very first and don't require reading the entire image into memory.

Comment: No body till told me about this class. Can I be able to create previews with different sizes as well as resolutions?